# Oracle compressed/b-tree index how and when to use

Tags: oracle, database-indexes

I would like to add a compressed index to the Oracle Applications workflow table `hr.pqh_ss_transaction_history` in order to access specific types of workflows (`process_name`) and workflows for specific people (`selected_person_id`).

There are lots of repeating values in `process_name` although the data is skewed. I would however want to access the `TFG_HR_NEW_HIRE_PLACE_JSP_PRC` and `TFG_HR_TERMINATION_JSP_PRC` process types.

```
"PROCESS_NAME","CNT"
"HR_GENERIC_APPROVAL_PRC",40347
"HR_PERSONAL_INFO_JSP_PRC",39284
"TFG_HR_NEW_HIRE_PLACE_JSP_PRC",18117
"TFG_HREMPSTS_TERMS_CHG_JSP_PRC",14076
"TFG_HR_TERMINATION_JSP_PRC",8764
"HR_ADV_INDIVIDUAL_COMP_PRC",4907
"TFG_HR_SIT_NOAPP",3979
"TFG_YE_TAX_PROV",2663
"HR_TERMINATION_JSP_PRC",1310
"HR_CHANGE_PAY_JSP_PRC",953
"TFG_HR_SIT_EXIT_JSP_PRC",797
"HR_SIT_JSP_PRC",630
"HR_QUALIFICATION_JSP_PRC",282
"HR_CAED_JSP_PRC",250
"TFG_HR_EMP_TERM_JSP_PRC",211
"PER_DOR_JSP_PRC",174
"HR_AWARD_JSP_PRC",101
"TFG_HR_SIT_REP_MOT",32
"TFG_HR_SIT_NEWPOS_NIB_JSP_PRC",30
"TFG_HR_SIT_NEWPOS_INBU_JSP_PRC",28
"HR_NEW_HIRE_PLACE_JSP_PRC",22
"HR_NEWHIRE_JSP_PRC",6
```

selected_person_id would obviously be more selective. Unfortunately there are 3774 nulls for this column and the highest count after that is 73 for one person. A lot of people would only have 1 row. The total row count is 136963.

My query would be in this format:

```
select psth.item_key,
       psth.creation_date,
       psth.last_update_date
from   hr.pqh_ss_transaction_history psth
where  nvl(psth.selected_person_id, :p_person_id) = :p_person_id
and    psth.process_name = 'HR_TERMINATION_JSP_PRC'
order  by psth.last_update_date
```

I am on Oracle 12c release 1.

I assume it would be a good idea to put a non-compressed b-tree index on `selected_person_id` since the values returned would fall in the less than 5% of the total rows scenario, but how do you handle the nulls in the column which would not go into the index when you select using `nvl(psth.selected_person_id, :p_person_id) = :p_person_id`? Is there a more efficient way to write the sql and how should you create this index?

For `process_name` I would like to use a compressed b-tree index. I am assuming that the statement is

```
CREATE INDEX idxname ON pqh_ss_transaction_history(process_name) COMPRESS
```

where there would be an implicit second column for `rowid`. Is it safe for it to use rowid here, since normally it is not advised to use rowid? Is the skewed data an issue (most of the time I would be selecting on the high volume side)? I don't understand how compressed indexes would be efficient. For b-tree indexes you would normally want to return 5% of the data, otherwise a full table scan is actually more efficient. How does the compressed index return so many `rowids` and then do lookup into the full table using those `rowids`, faster than a full table scan?

Or since the optimizer will only be able to use one of the two indexes should I rather create an uncompressed function based index with `selected_person_id` and `process_name` concatenated?

Comment: `where psth.selected_person_id = nvl(:p_person_id, psth.selected_person_id)` will never show rows where `psth.selected_person_id` is null. Is that intended?

Comment: Oops. Should be where nvl(psth.selected_person_id, :p_person_id) = :p_person_id

Comment: So whatever person_id you ask for, you get that one plus all of the rows with no person_id?

Comment: Yes, I want nulls and those where the :p_person_id matches the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idxname ON pqh_ss_transaction_history
  (process_name, NVL(selected_person_id,-1)) COMPRESS 1
```

Then change your query to:

```
select psth.item_key,
       psth.creation_date,
       psth.last_update_date
from   hr.pqh_ss_transaction_history psth
where  nvl(psth.selected_person_id, -1) in (:p_person_id,-1)
and    psth.process_name = 'HR_TERMINATION_JSP_PRC'
order  by psth.last_update_date
```

Comment: :p_person_id will always be something, it's just that Oracle for some reason does not always store the selected_person_id (even though it is the first thing that all workflows ask for).

Comment: OK, and you want your query to return all the rows where `selected_person_id` is null as well as those that match the :person_id value?

Comment: Yes, I want nulls and those where the :p_person_id matches the value.

Comment: Answer rewritten to suit the new requirements!

Comment: Should that not be CREATE INDEX idxname ON pqh_ss_transaction_history
  (process_name, NVL(selected_person_id,-1)) COMPRESS 1